# SugarCrm: How to find caller of a logic hook

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Suppose we have a before save logic hook on leads, now How we can detect if this called logic hook is:

> - a crm user who is saving a lead form
> - is a lead captured from on of entry points
> - is a save triggered by soap calls
> - is a workflow which is modifying lead fields
> - is called because of csv import
> - ...

I have checked some of the behaviors, it seems logic hooks are not called on workflows (at least in my test)
Also I hope to figure out this issue in global variables, but there are a lot of global variables.
**So How I can detect caller of a logic hook ?**

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I found to figure this out is to add a:

```
$GLOBALS['log']->fatal(print_r($_REQUEST,true));
```

To your logic hook. Then test each scenario that you need to account for and see how the request differs. Also check $_SESSION. You'll be able to find a few things that you can depend upon for your logic.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did eventually. I share some of my observations so it may help the others (these are statements, based on the case some of them may applies)

> - in third party entry point calls `$_SESSION` is empty, in direct entry    point calls is not so. Also in rest calls session is not empty.
> - rest calls have `$_REQUEST[rest_data]` and others don't.
> - entry point calls have `$_REQUEST[entryPoint]` available in the array
> - global `$current_user` is available, but the id var (`$current_user->id`)    is a string only in the case a user is submitting a form in crm.
> - in inline editing `$_REQUEST[action]` is equal to `saveHTMLField`
> - in user calls `$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]` is available and in other    calls it is not.

In a simple case this code shows how to detect user calls:

```
$trigger = false;
global $current_user;
if (!isset($current_user->id) || !strlen($current_user->id) > 2)
    $trigger = true;
if ($trigger) {
    //#My Custome Code
}
```